# Disable double click selection for SyntaxHighlighter

Tags: syntaxhighlighter

SyntaxHighlighter has a feature that allows code selection by double clicking. How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `quick-code` setting to false.

```
// Disable double click feature
SyntaxHighlighter.defaults['quick-code'] = false;

// Initialize SyntaxHighlighter
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
```

Tested on version 3.0.83.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the relevant lines in the source code. I'm still confused about how the default key is `quick-code` but the setting that's referenced is `quickCode`. I'm thinking it's something to do with his use of `opts-parser` https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/opts-parser.

https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter/blob/b35cee8468e87eaac6e303f0115c02626d1bef0f/src/defaults.js#L33

https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter/blob/b35cee8468e87eaac6e303f0115c02626d1bef0f/src/core.js#L152